# Usar o mesmo getInputStream() para 2 bufferedReader diferentes

Tags: java, http-request

Preciso de aceder a um ficheiro num servidor HTTP e retirar informação de 2 sitios diferentes dentro desse ficheiro. Neste momento consigo retirar de apenas um. A minha duvida é, posso simplesmente fazer:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

sendo que

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
```

ou preciso de fazer uma nova `HttpURLConnection` para isso?

Comment: Joper, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você não deve reusar *InputStream* dessa forma em hipótese alguma. Até pode funcionar dependendo de como for implementado, mas isso pode gerar erros piores. Por exemplo, quando um *stream* for fechado o outro também será fechado inadvertidamente. Dito isto, não consigo entender exatamente o que você está fazendo. Poderia editar a pergunta colocando um exemplo desse arquivo? Você está lendo o mesmo arquivo em dois sites diferentes ou um arquivo que contém duas informações?

Answer (score 2):

Não faz sentido criar dois `BufferedReader`s apontando para o mesmo `InputStream`. Na prática eles vão estar trabalhando em cima da mesma coisa.
Se você tentar ler um arquivo usando `BufferedReader` `in` e depois tentar ler o mesmo arquivo usando o `BufferedReader` `in2`, o `in2` vai continuar de onde o `in` parou.

Isso porque classes como `BufferedReader` e `InputStreamReader` estão apenas adicionando comportamento ao `InputStream`, mas o objeto continua sendo o mesmo.

Você precisa criar dois `InputStream`s. Ou você pode no mesmo `InputStream` retirar as duas informações que você precisa.